# Errors in UI tests have no location in Xcode (<unknown>:0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I recently added a UI Testing target to our existing project (which already has an iOS app target and a couple of other testing targets). Everything is working as expected and UI tests run without problems, but if a test fails the errors are never displayed in the file they occur and the Test Report shows them at `<unknown>:0` while the Issue Navigator shows them at `<unknown>`:

[image: Error as shown in Xcode]

It does mark the correct test as failed, but doesn't shown an error inside the editor. I looked through the build settings but couldn't find anything out of the ordinary.

Naturally, this makes debugging the tests much more annoying and harder. The usual clean/derived data/xcode restart magic hasn't done anything.

**Update**: After investigating further, it turns out that this is NOT a problem for assertion failures, which show up correctly.

Comment: Well, it did not find the element, it is looking for/tapping on. Check the way to element. The "<unknown>" fail is just generic message.

Comment: This is just an example, I can debug this an resolve the error, that's not the issue here. I'm wondering why XCode is not highlighting the line that causes this error (the line of code where I'm searching for the element)

Comment: Do you have "All exceptions" breakpoints turned on in XCode? Than it should stop on the line, which is crashing

Comment: Good advice, that does indeed work. It will not help on the CI, but at least it will help us debug issues locally :-)

Comment: Yep, wont work on CI, that for sure. You will probably need to add some if-else with waits for the element or something. If you need further help with the path to element or setting the conditions and waits etc, share more info :-)